# Get association objects with order from JoinTable using GORM

Tags: postgresql, go, join, go-gorm

I have two models

```
type Holder struct {
    OwnModel
    Title         string `json:"title"`
    Exercises []Exercise `json:"exercises" gorm:"many2many:holder_exercises_new;"`
}

type Exercise struct {
    OwnModel
    Title         string `json:"title"`
}
```

And join table

```
type HolderExercisesNew struct {
    OwnModel
    HolderID   int64 `json:"holder_id"`
    ExerciseID int64 `json:"exercise_id"`
    Order      int64 `json:"order"` // my custom param for ordering
}
```

I want to preload Exercises to Holders but ordered by "Order" param in join table.
For example i have

```
holders := []models.Holder{}
database.Preload("Exercises").Find(&holders)
```

It gives me holders with embedded exercises but in random order.
Is there a way to get Exercises in order set in join table?

Answer (score 0):

I tried what seemed obvious to me, which is using [Custom Preloading SQL](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Custom-Preloading-SQL):

```golang
holders := []models.Holder{}
database.
    Preload("Exercises", func(tx *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        return tx.Order("holder_exercises_new.order ASC")
    }).
    Find(&holders)
```

But that didn't work because GORM separates the loading into two queries, one of the join table and another of the joined table. A workaround I found would be, sans error checking:

```golang
holders := []models.Holder{}
database.Find(&holders)
for i := range holders {
    database.
        Model(&holders[i]).
        Order("holder_exercises_new.order ASC").
        Association("Exercises").
        Find(&holders[i].Exercises)
}
```